# Months zero based in android sdk

Tags: android, datepicker

Android sdk [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) states that months range from 0-11. What is the rationale behind this.

It seems strange since android sdk is the only one (i know of from my limited experience) which does this.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of multiples languages that do it this way, including C# which is the language I normally prefer to use.

There could be many reasons why but the it is mainly just to conform to the tradition of all variables within programming to start at 0 rather than 1.

Comment: Why not do the same with days 0 - [27 | 29 | 30 ]

Comment: It isn't just a tradition, there's strong hardware reasons for it.

Comment: Android sdk doesn't do the same with days.

Comment: Day of the month i can understand as 1-31 as to avoid confusion as the max value is not always the same, (ie. hour of the day max is always 24 thus its 0-23). Makes sense to me, others like joda time who do it from 1-12 seems a little confusing in my mind

Answer (score 0):

Most languages and frameworks do this.  Originally this was based on C enums, which default to starting from 0.  The reason for that is that you could then use the value directly as an array index.  Arrays start from 0 because arrays are implemented with each object a fixed length offset from a memory address, and if you didn't index from 0 you'd either have to do a subtraction on every access or waste memory by allocating an extra object per array.